# Could not fetch email address from LinkedIn REST Api v2

Tags: email, scope, permissions, linkedin-api

- I have already authenticated user using oauth2.0.
- I have passed scopes like "r_basicprofile" and "r_emailaddress".
- Also I have tried this url https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/primary-contact-api#email and I get error as below:

  ```
  {
      "serviceErrorCode": 100,
      "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-members /clientAwareMemberHandles",
      "status": 403
  }
  ```
- Checked all the basic and full profile parameters from https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people here, but could not fetch email address. Please help me with this. Thank you.
- Reference: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2

Comment: what was the URL you used to make the request?

Comment: @Drv, Any updates? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: Same here. It was working until a few days ago... I have tryed the following endpoints:
`clientAwareMemberHandles?q=members&projection=(elements*(primary,type,handle~))
emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`

And I get the following response:

`
{ elements:
I/ReactNativeJS( 3960):    [ { handle: 'urn:li:emailAddress:299467931',
I/ReactNativeJS( 3960):        'handle!':
I/ReactNativeJS( 3960):         { message: 'Unsupported URN domain: li:emailAddress',
I/ReactNativeJS( 3960):           status: 501 } } ] }
`